# Control enum value format during (de)serialization via attributes

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

### The Problem

Let's say I have an enum representing something or other:

```
public enum ResultState
{
    Found,
    Deleted,
    NotFound
}
```

In my serialized json, I'd like these values to be serialized as `"found"`, `"gone"` or `"not_found"` respectively. (Note: this is *not* camelCase, but rather a totally custom string!)

**I'm using JSON.NET**

### The Story So Far

I've got everything working almost right - enums are globally converted to strings via the `StringEnumConverter`, however I can't for the life of me see how to achieve something similar to the above.

My initial thoughts were to apply the `JsonProperty(...)` attribute to the relevant enum values, however this doesn't seem to work!

### Potential Solution?

The only way I can think of getting this work is to write my own `JsonConverter` inheriting from `StringEnumConverter`, but with some additional magic to handle a new `JsonName` attribute I'd create.

As you might imagine, I don't relish the idea of this.

**I was wondering if you wonderful people could suggest a simpler alternative?**

Comment: It is surprisingly easy to create a new converter subclass.  You probably could have done it in the time it took you to ask this question :)

Comment: You're probably right, but I wanted a more declarative approach. Turns out that the `EnumMemberAttribute` was staring me in the face the whole time. *facepalm*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it happens, I was overthinking the whole thing.

I made use of the `EnumMember` attribute from `System.Runtime.Serialization`, which worked great.

Here's my new enum for completeness:

```
public enum QueryResultState
{
    [EnumMember(Value="found")]
    Found,

    [EnumMember(Value="gone")]
    Deleted,

    [EnumMember(Value="not_found")]
    NotFound
}
```

Don't forget to include the `StringEnumConverter` when calling `JsonConvert.Serialize(...)`, as JSON.NET serializes Enums to Integers by default:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObjectWithAnEnum, new StringEnumConverter());
```

Comment: I don't get how this works? I tried `QueryResultState r = QueryResultState.Deleted;
            var r2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { a = r });` and got `{"a":1}`

Comment: In addition to the above, you still need to use the StringEnumConverter. Pass one in on the SerializeObject overload.

Comment: Any reason not to include this info in your answer?

Comment: It's in my original question - about halfway down.

Comment: Dan, There is nothing connecting `EnumMember` to `StringEnumConverter` in your answer. Think for future readers and complete your answer. until then `-1`