# Custom serialization of enums in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, enums

Referencing this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178593/control-enum-value-format-during-deserialization-via-attributes) about custom serialization of strings to enums and vice versa in Json.NET, decorating the enum members using the EnumMember attribute - is there a way to get MongoDB to perform the same feat?

I have just refactored some previously string fields to enums and was wondering if there is any way to instruct Mongo to also read the EnumMember values when (de-)serializing and avoid me having to go through the database and update all the current text values.

Comment: FYI - I went with a JS update of the relevant fields in the collection - simple enough. Would still be interesting to know if this is possible tho.

Answer (score 1):

i´m using package:  PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Bson" Version="2.12.1"

my map class:

```
    public class OfferMap
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Offer>(map => //Offer is a class
        {
            map.AutoMap();
            map.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);

            map
            .SetIsRootClass(true);

            map
            .MapMember(x => x.OfferType)
            .SetSerializer(new EnumSerializer<OfferType>(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.String)) // OfferType is an Enum
            .SetElementName("offerType")
            .SetIgnoreIfNull(false)
            .SetIsRequired(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a CustomEnumSerializer to handle the EnumMember attribute

```
public class CustomEnumSerializer<TEnum> : StructSerializerBase<TEnum>, IRepresentationConfigurable<CustomEnumSerializer<TEnum>> where TEnum : struct
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, object>> _fromValueMap = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, object>>(); // string representation to Enum value map

    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<object, string>> _toValueMap = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<object, string>>(); // Enum value to string map

    // private fields
    private readonly BsonType _representation;

    // constructors
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="EnumSerializer{TEnum}"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public CustomEnumSerializer()
        : this((BsonType)0) // 0 means use underlying type
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="EnumSerializer{TEnum}"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="representation">The representation.</param>
    public CustomEnumSerializer(BsonType representation)
    {
        switch (representation)
        {
            case 0:
            case BsonType.Int32:
            case BsonType.Int64:
            case BsonType.String:

                break;

            default:
                var message = string.Format("{0} is not a valid representation for an EnumSerializer.", representation);
                throw new ArgumentException(message);
        }

        // don't know of a way to enforce this at compile time
        var enumTypeInfo = typeof(TEnum).GetTypeInfo();
        if (!enumTypeInfo.IsEnum)
        {
            var message = string.Format("{0} is not an enum type.", typeof(TEnum).FullName);
            throw new BsonSerializationException(message);
        }

        _representation = representation;

        if (representation == BsonType.String)
        {
            var enumType = typeof(TEnum);
            if (!_fromValueMap.ContainsKey(enumType))
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> fromMap = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
                Dictionary<object, string> toMap = new Dictionary<object, string>();

                FieldInfo[] fields = enumType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

                foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
                {
                    string name = field.Name;
                    object enumValue = Enum.Parse(enumType, name);

                    // use EnumMember attribute if exists
                    EnumMemberAttribute enumMemberAttrbiute = field.GetCustomAttribute<EnumMemberAttribute>();

                    if (enumMemberAttrbiute != null)
                    {
                        string enumMemberValue = enumMemberAttrbiute.Value;

                        fromMap[enumMemberValue] = enumValue;
                        toMap[enumValue] = enumMemberValue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        toMap[enumValue] = name;
                    }

                    fromMap[name] = enumValue;
                }

                _fromValueMap[enumType] = fromMap;
                _toValueMap[enumType] = toMap;
            }
        }
    }

    // public properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the representation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The representation.
    /// </value>
    public BsonType Representation
    {
        get { return _representation; }
    }

    // public methods
    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes a value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The deserialization context.</param>
    /// <param name="args">The deserialization args.</param>
    /// <returns>A deserialized value.</returns>
    public override TEnum Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        var bsonReader = context.Reader;

        var bsonType = bsonReader.GetCurrentBsonType();
        switch (bsonType)
        {
            case BsonType.Int32: return (TEnum)Enum.ToObject(typeof(TEnum), bsonReader.ReadInt32());
            case BsonType.Int64: return (TEnum)Enum.ToObject(typeof(TEnum), bsonReader.ReadInt64());
            case BsonType.Double: return (TEnum)Enum.ToObject(typeof(TEnum), (long)bsonReader.ReadDouble());
            case BsonType.String:
                var fromValue = FromValue(typeof(TEnum), bsonReader.ReadString());
                return (TEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), fromValue.ToString());
            default:
                throw CreateCannotDeserializeFromBsonTypeException(bsonType);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes a value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The serialization context.</param>
    /// <param name="args">The serialization args.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The object.</param>
    public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, TEnum value)
    {
        var bsonWriter = context.Writer;

        switch (_representation)
        {
            case 0:
                var underlyingTypeCode = Type.GetTypeCode(Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(TEnum)));
                if (underlyingTypeCode == TypeCode.Int64 || underlyingTypeCode == TypeCode.UInt64)
                {
                    goto case BsonType.Int64;
                }
                else
                {
                    goto case BsonType.Int32;
                }

            case BsonType.Int32:
                bsonWriter.WriteInt32(Convert.ToInt32(value));
                break;

            case BsonType.Int64:
                bsonWriter.WriteInt64(Convert.ToInt64(value));
                break;

            case BsonType.String:
                var val = ToValue(typeof(TEnum), value);
                bsonWriter.WriteString(val);
                break;

            default:
                throw new BsonInternalException("Unexpected EnumRepresentation.");
        }
    }

    private string ToValue(Type enumType, object obj)
    {
        Dictionary<object, string> map = _toValueMap[enumType];

        return map[obj];
    }
    private object FromValue(Type enumType, string value)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> map = _fromValueMap[enumType];

        if (!map.ContainsKey(value))
            return value;

        return map[value];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a serializer that has been reconfigured with the specified representation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="representation">The representation.</param>
    /// <returns>The reconfigured serializer.</returns>
    public CustomEnumSerializer<TEnum> WithRepresentation(BsonType representation)
    {
        if (representation == _representation)
        {
            return this;
        }
        else
        {
            return new CustomEnumSerializer<TEnum>(representation);
        }
    }

    // explicit interface implementations
    IBsonSerializer IRepresentationConfigurable.WithRepresentation(BsonType representation)
    {
        return WithRepresentation(representation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed a custom deserializer that would return the default value when encountering an unexpected value in the data, rather than the default behavior of throwing a deserialization exception.

```
   public class CustomEnumSerializer<TEnum>: MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.EnumSerializer<TEnum>
        where TEnum : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
    {
        public override TEnum Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
        {
            var bsonReader = context.Reader;
            var bsonType = bsonReader.GetCurrentBsonType();
            var val = "";

            switch (bsonType)
            {
                case BsonType.String:
                    val = bsonReader.ReadString() ?? "";
                    break;
                case BsonType.Int32:
                    val = bsonReader.ReadInt32().ToString();
                    break;
                case BsonType.Int64:
                    val = bsonReader.ReadInt64().ToString();
                    break;
                case BsonType.Null:
                    return default(TEnum);
                default:
                    return base.Deserialize(context, args);
            }

            if(Enum.TryParse(val, true, out TEnum result)){
                return result;
            }
            return default(TEnum);
        }

    }
```

To implement it in your repository:

```
    static MyRepository()
    {
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyDataType>(ms =>
        {
            ms.AutoMap();
            ms.GetMemberMap(i => i.MyEnum)
            .SetSerializer(new CustomEnumSerializer<MyEnumType>());
        });
    }
```